# how to resolve error on circleci "bash: line 1: bundle: command not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, circleci

My tests were all passing yesterday on circle and are still passing today locally but now I this error message. Whats going on?

```
bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3 
bash: line 1: bundle: command not found
bash: line 1: bundle: command not found

bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3  returned exit code 127

Action failed: bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I fully believe that CircleCI doesn't test anything before pushing it out:

https://discuss.circleci.com/t/bundle-command-not-found/3783

Basically, you know have to explicitly install bundler.

Add `gem install bundler` to the `pre` stage of the `dependencies` in your `circle.yml` file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for CircleCI 2.0 that uses docker images.

Solution was to delete my `.ruby-gemset` from repo, after that CI was able to use default gemset and bundler could continue.